Does $(\log_a x)^{\log_a x} = O(2^{(\log_2 x)^2})$?
I was wondering if anyone had a simple way to evaluate the asymptotic relation between $f(x) = (\log_a x)^{\log_a x}$ and $g(x) = 2^{(\log_2 x)^2}$, where $a$ is any real (that is, whether each of the claims are true or false: $f = O(g)$ and $f = \Omega(g)$).
This is a practice problem from the textbook I am now studying, and in its original presentation this problem omitted a base from the logarithm in $f(x)$, writing merely $\log x$; it included a base of $2$ in $g(x)$. Some approaches I took towards solving this problem were substituting $y = \log_a x$, trying to take the logarithm of both sides, and evaluating the limit at infinity of the ratio of $f$ and $g$; but I found things still too complicated. I would appreciate it if anyone could present a way of seeing the asymptotic relationship here.

As noticed by @Angelo, it suffices to prove that $f=o(g)$ (you forgot to specify: "as $x\to\infty$", and to assume $a>1$).
This is equivalent to $\lim_\infty\frac fg=0$, i.e. $\lim_\infty(\log_2f-\log_2g)=-\infty$. Now, as $y:=\log_ax\to\infty$,
$$\log_2f(x)-\log_2g(x)=y^2\left(\frac{\log_2y}y-(\log_2a)^2\right)\to-\infty$$
indeed, since $\frac{\log_2y}y\to0$.

Instead of $y^2\left(\frac{\log_2y}y-(\log_2a)^2\right)$, should it not instead be $y^2\left(\frac{\log_2y}y-(\log_2x)^2\right)$, as $g(x) = 2^{(\log_2x)^2}$?

No, it is correct, as $y\log_2a=\log_2x$.

We assume $a>1$ and we concern the asyptotic behavior as $x\rightarrow +\infty$. Note that
$$2^{(\log_2x)^2}=x^{\log_2x}=(x^{\log_2a})^{\log_ax}$$
It is obvious that $x^{\log_2a}$ runs faster than $\log_ax$, so $(\log_a x)^{\log_a x}=O(2^{(\log_2 x)^2})$.

Regarding how you note that it is obvious that $x^{\log_2 a}$ runs faster than $\log_a x$- I can see this by taking the limit of their ratio at infinity and applying l'hopital's; but what could be a way to intuitively see this without doing computations like that?

Remember polynomial runs faster than logarithm.

But $x^{\log_2 a}$ isn't necessarily a polynomial, as its exponent may not be an integer, right?

You can see $x^{\log_2 a}$ as a new variable $y$. Then $\log _a x=\frac{1}{\log _2a}\log _a y$

If we prove that $f=o(g)$, then we get as a direct consequence that $f=O(g)$ is true and $f=\Omega(g)$ is false, indeed all functions $o(g)$ are also $O(g)$ but none of them is $\Omega(g)$ since $\Omega(g)$ is the negation of $o(g)$.
So now we will prove that $f=o(g)$, that is, for any $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $x_{\varepsilon}\in\Bbb R$ such that $\left|f(x)\right|\leqslant\varepsilon\!\cdot\!g(x)$ for any $x\in[x_\varepsilon,+\infty)$.
It is necessary that $a>1$, otherwise the following function $f$ would not be defined on a neighbourhood of $+\infty$.
$f(x)=(\log_ax)^{\log_ax}:(1,+\infty)\to\Bbb R\;\;,\;\;$ where $a>1\;,$
$g(x)=2^{(\log_2x)^2}:(0,+\infty)\to\Bbb R$.
For any $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $\;x_{\varepsilon}\!=\!\max\!\left\{\!e^{-\!\ln a\cdot\ln\varepsilon},e^{\frac{9\ln^2\!2}{\ln^2\!a}}\!\right\}\!>\!1\;$ such that for any $\;x\in[x_{\varepsilon},+\infty)\;$ it results that
$\begin{align}\left|f(x)\right|&=\left|(\log_ax)^{\log_ax}\right|=(\log_ax)^{\log_ax}=e^{\log_ax\ln(\log_ax)}=\\[3pt]&=e^{\frac{\ln x}{\ln a}\ln\left(\frac{\ln x}{\ln a}\right)}=e^{\frac{\ln x}{\ln a}\big[\ln(\ln x)-\ln(\ln a)\big]}=\\[3pt]&=e^{\frac{\ln x}{\ln a}\big[2\ln(\sqrt{\ln x}\,)-\frac{\ln a\ln x}{\ln2}+\frac{\ln a\ln x}{\ln2}-\ln(\ln a)\big]}\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\underset{\overbrace{\ln t<t\;\text{ for any }t>0}}{<}\\[3pt]&<e^{\frac{\ln x}{\ln a}\big[2\sqrt{\ln x}-\frac{\ln a\ln x}{\ln2}+\frac{\ln a\ln x}{\ln2}-\ln(\ln a)\big]}=\\[3pt]&=e^{\frac{\ln x}{\ln a}\big[\sqrt{\ln x}\left(2-\frac{\ln a\sqrt{\ln x}}{\ln2}\right)+\frac{\ln a\ln x}{\ln2}-\ln(\ln a)\big]}\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\underset{\overbrace{\text{because }x\geqslant x_{\epsilon}\geqslant e^{\frac{9\ln^2\!2}{\ln^2\!a}}}}{\leqslant}\\[3pt]&\leqslant e^{\frac{\ln x}{\ln a}\big[\sqrt{\ln x}\big(2-3\big)+\frac{\ln a\ln x}{\ln2}-\ln(\ln a)\big]}=\\[3pt]&=e^{\frac{\ln x}{\ln a}\big[-\sqrt{\ln x}\,+\frac{\ln a\ln x}{\ln2}-\ln(\ln a)\big]}\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\underset{\overbrace{\text{because }x\geqslant x_{\epsilon}\geqslant e^{\frac{9\ln^2\!2}{\ln^2\!a}}>e^{\frac1{\ln^2\!a}}}}{<}\\[3pt]&<e^{\frac{\ln x}{\ln a}\big[-\frac1{\ln a}\,+\frac{\ln a\ln x}{\ln2}-\ln(\ln a)\big]}=\\[3pt]&=e^{\frac{\ln x}{\ln a}\left[-1-\left(\frac1{\ln a}-1\right)+\frac{\ln a\ln x}{\ln2}-\ln(\ln a)\right]}\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\underset{\overbrace{\ln(1+t)\leqslant t\;\text{ for any }t>-1}}{\leqslant}\\[3pt]&\leqslant e^{\frac{\ln x}{\ln a}\left\{-1-\ln\left[1+\left(\frac1{\ln a}-1\right)\right]+\frac{\ln a\ln x}{\ln2}-\ln(\ln a)\right\}}=\\[3pt]&=e^{\frac{\ln x}{\ln a}\left[-1-\ln\left(\frac1{\ln a}\right)+\frac{\ln a\ln x}{\ln2}-\ln(\ln a)\right]}=\\[3pt]&=e^{\frac{\ln x}{\ln a}\left[-1+\ln\left(\ln a\right)+\frac{\ln a\ln x}{\ln2}-\ln(\ln a)\right]}=\\[3pt]&=e^{-\frac{\ln x}{\ln a}+\frac{\ln^2\!x}{\ln2}}=e^{-\frac{\ln x}{\ln a}+\frac{(\log_2\!x\cdot\ln2)^2}{\ln2}}=e^{-\frac{\ln x}{\ln a}+\left(\log_2\!x\right)^2\cdot\ln2}=\\[3pt]&=e^{-\frac{\ln x}{\ln a}}\cdot2^{(\log_2x)^2}\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\underset{\overbrace{\text{because }x\geqslant x_{\epsilon}\geqslant e^{-\!\ln a\cdot\ln\varepsilon}}}{\leqslant}\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!e^{\ln\varepsilon}\cdot2^{(\log_2x)^2}=\varepsilon\!\cdot\!g(x)\;.\end{align}$
So we have proved that ,
for any $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $\;x_{\epsilon}\!=\!\max\!\left\{\!e^{-\!\ln a\cdot\ln\varepsilon},e^{\frac{9\ln^2\!2}{\ln^2\!a}}\!\right\}\!>\!1\;$ such that for any $x\!\in\![x_{\varepsilon},\!+\infty)$ it results that $\,\left|f(x)\right|\!\leqslant\!\varepsilon\!\cdot\!g(x)\,,$
that is, $\,f=o(g)\,.$

regarding $a>1$: wouldn't this still define the function on that neighborhood, but just make the values of the function negative? I am trying to understand why, in order to have a well-defined problem, $a>1$ must be true

@PrincessMia, if $r$ is any negative non-integer number, then $r^r$ cannot be defined in the field of real numbers. For example $(-\frac56)^{-\frac56}$ and $(-\sqrt2)^{-\sqrt2}$ are not real numbers. So $h(x)=x^x$ is not a real-valued function on the interval $(-\infty,0)$. For the same reason, if $0<a<1$, $f(x)=(\log_ax)^{\log_ax}$ is not a real-valued function on $(1,+\infty)$, but it is a real-valued function just on the interval $(0,1)$.

@PrincessMia, in my answer I explained in detail why $f=o(g)$. Is it sufficiently clear what I wrote ? Is there something which is not enough understandable? I hope you like my answer.
